# Boost 1.57.0 Program Options MSVS 2013 Linker Error

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, visual-studio-2013, linker

I am attempting to update my code and libraries for use in Visual Studio 2013 but I am having problems with Boost 1.57.0.  For whatever reason MSVC 12.0 refuses to properly compile program_options due to two linker errors (either building a project with program_options being used or attempt to build the library itself).

I have tried building the library but these linker errors were preventing it.  I also get these errors using the pre-built SourceForge binaries located here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.57.0/

These are the linker errors I am getting:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "`class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > boost::program_options::arg`" (?arg@program_options@boost@@3V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A)
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "`public: static unsigned int const boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length`"
>   (?m_default_line_length@options_description@program_options@boost@@2IB)

I have been Googling this problem for the last three hours but I have found no solutions to this problem (several previously posted solutions for very old versions of Boost have not worked for me).

Some other information:

library name: libboost_program_options-vc120-mt-1_57
RT Library: Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)

If you need any other info let me know and I will add it to the o. post.

Comment: Are you linking with boost options (you *have* to) ? How did you configure your project to do so ?

Comment: @quantdev Not sure why it was not working earlier.  I had my boost files (everything) in my project folder.  When I moved them back out to how I had my previous boost install setup and re-did the include/library directory settings it works now.

Answer (score 4):

You have to link to the static library. Try linking to `boost_program_options-vc100-mt-sgd-1_47.lib` instead of `libboost_program_options-vc120-mt-gd-1_57.lib`.

The s indicates the static version of the library. You can check [Boost Library Naming](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming)for more details about the naming conventions.

To fix the multiple definition linker errors, change the Visual Studio Runtime Library option in Configuration Properties >> C/C++ >> Code Generation >> Runtime Library from  Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) to Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd).

Answer (score 0):

You can define this to solve the issue:

```
BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_DYN_LINK=1
```

If you use **cmake**, you can write this:

```
add_compile_definitions("BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_DYN_LINK=1")
```